# Word for "walking along but not on top"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> “Sure we should go in?” I asked Mary as we walked along the wall of a
>   high school.

Obviously, they aren't walking on top of the wall. What's the correct way to describe that they were walking beside the wall?

Comment: What's wrong with "walking beside the wall"? That seems to explain the situation admirably.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I thought "beside" wouldn't imply "along"?

Comment: If you walk beside a wall, but it's not along it, you are walking away from the wall and only beside it instantaneously. If you carry on walking, you're no longer beside it. To walk beside a wall, it must be along it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach makes sense ... should I delete the question or keep it?

Comment: *Alongside* is another possibility, so there is more than answer; there may be other prepositions which work. It's on-topic, I think (just). Up to you whether you keep it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Actually "alongside" is the correct answer. Maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: 'Beside' is fine, but so is 'along'. Unless there's context to indicate otherwise, readers wouldn't assume they're on top of the wall. Consider 'walking along the river' -- what's your first thought there?

Comment: @JimMack Depends on whether the subject is Jesus. :)

Comment: Please see  [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) about such questions. We are not a word-puzzle and crossword puzzle site; we're a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language enthusiasts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments are illuminating, but the question deserves an answer, I think.

**"Along"** clearly conveys the relationship between the walkers and the wall, as do both **"alongside"** and **"beside."**

Because prepositional phrases are often idiomatic, there are few rules beyond common sense and logic to guide a writer to the "correct" preposition.  The community of traditional users of English has determined over time which usages are "preferred."  The researcher is thus left with lists of idioms.

Wood (1967) offers a potentially useful reference, *English Prepositional Idioms.*  A more immediately accessible (if lengthy) resource can be found at http://www.advanced-english-grammar.com/list-of-prepositional-phrases.html

Answer (score 0):

The phrase that would differ least from what you wrote would be "walked along by the wall".